# Understanding a Microsoft Office Access SQL query with 'IIF'

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

On a larger project, I am migrating dozens of queries from a Microsoft Office Access database (MDB) to Oracle.

While I was able to understand nearly all of the insane constructs that are possible to write in Access, I failed on a single one.

The (simplified) query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable

WHERE 
Left(SomeField,3)=IIf(SomeParameter="GYM",Mid(SomeField,2,1)<>'0') 

AND 
Left(SomeField,3)=IIf(SomeParameter="GYM",Left(SomeField,3)<>'110')
```

Here, `SomeField` is a column in the table and `SomeParameter` is an input to the query.

What I do not understand is the `WHERE` part:

- Why is the `else` part missing from the `IIF` statement?
- Why is a string compared to the result of an `<>` operation (i.e. a boolean)?

Since it successfully runs in Access, the query *is* valid. I failed to even generate some test data that will pass the comparison.

Any hints on how to interpret the comparison?

Comment: No results, unfortunately. I tried to fill example data and pass `"GYM"` and non-`"GYM"` as the `SomeParameter`, without any luck.

Comment: @Uwe - Yes I deleted that question as I hadn't noticed the part where you said "I failed to even generate some test data that will pass the comparison"

Comment: `SELECT cstr(iif(true,true)), cstr(iif(true,false))` returns `-1,0`. I get an "Invalid use of NULL" error if I try `cstr(iif(false,true))` Not sure which datatype has greater precedence either.

Comment: `'-1 '` passes this test

Comment: Uh, I don't understand this string of comments. Have you just discovered that Access and VBA use -1 as the value for TRUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I share the original questioner's puzzlement over this expression:

```
  WHERE Left(SomeField,3)=IIf(SomeParameter="GYM",Mid(SomeField,2,1)<>'0')
```

Let's unpack that:

If SomeParameter = "GYM" return this:

```
  Mid(SomeField,2,1)<>'0'
```

This is testing the second character in SomeField against the string "0", so it means that there's a badly designed field, in that the second character in that field has independent meaning. This will return true for all values where the 2nd character is anything but 0.

Whatever it returns (True or Null in the False case), it will be compared to this string:

```
  Left(SomeField,3)
```

If The first three characters of SomeField happen to be "Yes" then it might very well produce a true comparison, since in Access/Jet/ACE, Yes and True and -1 are all equivalent, and string representations can be implicitly coerced.

So, this might return rows that look like this:

```
  SomeParameter  SomeField
  GYM            Yes sir, that's my baby
```

However, it really makes not a lot of sense, as the test of SomeField is circular. That is, you're comparing to the first 3 characters of the field in an instance in which a true comparison can only happen when the first three characters are "Yes", but you're in turn comparing those first three characters to a test for whether or not the 2nd character in the same field <> 0. In all cases where the first three characters are "Yes" then the second character will definitely not be "0" so you really only need to test the value of the first three characters.

I vote for incompetence on the part of the original developer.

Comment: `Yes sir, that's my baby` doesn't actually pass the condition though. Perhaps you could explain why? `IIF(Left('Yes sir, thats my baby',3)= ('Yes'<>'110'),"T","F")` returns `F` but `IIF(Left('Yes sir, thats my baby',3)= true,"T","F")` returns `T`. why should hardcoding `true` as opposed to a condition that evaluates to `true` make any difference? Or to simpify it `'Yes'= ('Yes'<>'110')` returns `0` but `'Yes'= true` returns `-1`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @David-W-Fenton. Most likely I'll throw away the whole SQL query and ask my customer what kind of data they _want_. The original developer(s) of the code is not available anymore (Dated from around 1999).

Comment: @Martin: you've mixed up the conditions. The test is whether `Left("Yes sir, thats my baby",3)=("E"<>"0")`. The left hand of the = will return "Yes" while the right-hand side returns True. "Yes"=True may or may not be implicitly coerced so that it will return True. The fact that "Yes"=True returns -1 proves my point, since -1 is the value for True in Access/Jet/ACE and VB/VBA.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

```
iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false )
```

So it's like a ternary operator in C++/C# etc.Looks like they don't care about if the value is false.

Also, I wonder if they didn't screw up the logic :)

**EDIT** 
I believe it returns Null if the false condition isn't specified.

In which case it would appear that they're setting a field to either true (when the condition <> is true) or null, when it's false.

Seems like an odd design to me

Comment: But what does the expression return if false and no `else` is specified? `true`? `false`? `unknown`? And what happens when you compare it to a string?

Comment: Updated my answer... believe it returns NULL when the "false condition" is met, if no code is specified.

Comment: Yes, it returns Null. You can see this with `SELECT InNull(IIf(1=2,True))`, which returns -1 (True). The IIf() function does not require a FALSE case when executed in SQL. In VBA, however, it does require it. I share the puzzlement of the original questioner, though, as it's comparing a substring of 3 characters either to a Null or to True (-1).

Answer (score 1):

The first iif will return Null if `SomeParameter<>"GYM"`, otherwise it will return `True` or `False` depending on the boolean evaluation of the expression `Mid(SomeField,2,1)<>'0'`.

Same logic for the second iif.

Let me guess....is that a query in the finance industry ?  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @iDevelop. It's government-related, no finance industry :-). Can you explain the comparison of a string with the boolean value?

Comment: Uwe, it's no different than if you did a "WHERE Field <> 'ABC'"  Only here, you're checking somefield doesn't equal 0, that it's anything but 0.  It's not actually comparing a string with a boolean, it's comparing a string with a string and returning a boolean

Comment: Mid(SomeField,2,1)<>'0' will return -1 for TRUE or 0 for FALSE. If Left(SomeField,3) is equal to that, the expression should be True. I suspect this is always False...